# How do I make a network request in Qt binding to a specific interface/IP?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtnetwork, qthttp

So as of Qt 5, [QHttp is deprecated](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/sourcebreaks.html#changes-to-qt-network) and we're all supposed to [use QNetworkAccessManager now](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details). Fine. But how do I make a request (HTTP or otherwise) from my multihomed machine without feeling like I'm playing roulette?

If [there is no way](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-21692), then what is a workaround? For my specific case right now, I just need to download a file via HTTP. But is there really no way to do this in a generic way with QtNetwork?

Comment: Is this still unresolved one year later??

Answer (score 1):

The quick workaround would be to use this in your project file

```
QT += http
```

It is still available in a [separate module](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qthttp/source/36f370ac28c5864da5bc1cbd61980e053c1cb4c9%3a) for compatibility.

Comment: It is true. But, from the docs ... "We strongly advise against using it in new code." So, I was hoping for a solution people are already using for new code.

Comment: @njahnke: to me, it does not matter what they advise if they do not provide alternatives. I have been a happy user of qthttp thus far without worries, but yes, it is just a quick workaround as written.

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky enough that the desired interface is a separate physical (hardware) interface, you can do e.g. (`web_view` is a `QWebView*`):

```
QNetworkConfigurationManager config_manager;
QList<QNetworkConfiguration> configs = config_manager.allConfigurations();
bool found_interface = false;
QString desired_interface_name("eth1");
foreach (const QNetworkConfiguration &config, configs) {
    if (config.name() == desired_interface_name) {
        found_interface = true;
        QNetworkAccessManager *network_access_manager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
        network_access_manager->setConfiguration(config);
        web_view->page()->setNetworkAccessManager(network_access_manager);
        break;
    }
}
if (!found_interface) {
    //we failed to find the interface!
}
```

Again, this will not work if the IP is bound to a virtual interface part of one physical interface (e.g. `eth1:1`, `eth1:2`, etc). I am still looking for a solution for that case.

Comment: @njajnke do you manage to succesfully bind the QNetworkAccessManager? I tested some times ago a similar code, but it was not working for me on a multi-homed system (i.e. eth0, eth1) Requests were always routed via default gw